# Can two std::atomic's be part of one union?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I want to do this:

```
union {
    std::atomic<uint128_t> u128;
    struct {
        std::atomic<uint64_t> u64_1;
        std::atomic<uint64_t> u64_2;
    };
};
```

Several threads will read and write both parts of the union.

Is it safe?

**Edit:** I use Linux, x86_64, clang 3.3

**Edit2:** I want to be able to increment and decrement u64_1, read u64_2, and write u128 (compare_exchange)

**Edit3:** What if I use [atomic builtin functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html)? The union will look like this:

```
union {
    uint128_t u128;
    struct {
        uint64_t u64_1;
        uint64_t u64_2;
    };
};
```

u64_1 will map to first half of u128 and u64_2 will map to second half.

Comment: Does your platform support 128bit atomic writes natively?

Comment: Due to aliasing restrictions (at least) you cannot write to u128 and read from u64_1 and u64_2, or vice versa. Also C++, even C++11, does not have anonymous structs.

Comment: Looks like a BFG-3000 with a built-in foot detector to me...

Comment: @dribeas, yes, CMPXCHG16 instruction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::atomic<T>` operations can be either lockless or locking, depending on whether the architecture offers the underlying guarantees. You can check this by checking `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free()`.

If the type is not lock free, it might be supported by the library by means of a counter. That in turn probably means that the type is no longer a POD underneath, which in turn means that it is your responsibility to call the constructors/destructors when switching from one active member of the union to another.

If there is a mutex for the 128 bit but not the 64bit types you might end up with a situation in which the layout of the values coincides, but the atomicity of operations is guaranteed by different means, so it might seem to work, but fail spuriously and in a way that is hard to even detect.

Comment: § 29.5/5 says "The atomic integral specializations and the specialization `atomic<bool>` shall have standard layout. They
shall each have a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor. They shall each support aggregate
initialization syntax." So no constructor/destructor calls are necessary to switch the active union member.

Comment: @Casey: Yes, I was reading this before I wrote the answer. The question is whether `uint128_t` is an *integral type* according to the standard. The important point is that if the type is not natively supported, it will need to use some underlying synchronization mechanism, and there is no guarantee that the synchronization mechanism is standard layout or not.

Comment: @Casey: Also note that *standard-layout* and *POD* are not equivalent. All PODs are standard layout, but not all standard layout types are POD. Read the second paragraph as: if the `std::atomic<T>` does not have a *trivial-constructor*...

Comment: So it's safe as long as it's lock-free?

Comment: @alkedr: Almost guaranteed to be unsafe if not lock-free, but if it is lock-free I would still look into what the hardware offers and what your library implementation does. `uint128_t` is not an standard type, and there are not that many platforms with 128bit registers, so I would be surprised if this can be guaranteed. It also depends on what operations you are doing, if it is only read/writes or if you are using any other feature (way atomic increments or decrements...). I would not venture to say that it is safe even if it is lock-free

Comment: @dribeas, CMPXCHG16 instruction is supported by majority of 64-bit processors. 128bit registers aren't necessary, two 64-bit registers are used instead.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking this is not safe. The note (admitedly non-normative) in 29.5/9 tells us that:

> [ Note: The representation of an atomic specialization need not have
>   the same size as its corresponding argument type. Specializations
>   should have the same size whenever possible, as this reduces the
>   effort required to port existing code. —end note ]

So right up front we aren't guaranteed that the two pieces even have the same size. Further, you have to make sure that you aren't using an atomic operation on one member while another thread changes the active member in another.

Comment: Both members are active all the time

Comment: @alkedr The C++ standard explicitly says that only one member of a union is active at a time.

Comment: @alkedr: Mark is correct. It is a complete myth that unions can have multiple active members at any given time. Plenty of people use unions for this sole reason and they are all wrong. `[C++11 9.5/1]: In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time. [..]`

Answer (score 0):

It should be okay as long as

1  you respect strict aliasing;

2  you don't update `u128` and either of `u64_1` or `u64_2` concurrently (which is of course not protected here and makes no sense anyway);

3  you don't expect `u64_1` and `u64_1` to map the first and second 64 bits of `u128`.

I don't actually see any benefit from this construct. Perhaps you can clarify why this construct should be helpful. I think you may be better off without the `u128` (i.e. without a union).

Comment: I think he wants threads to concurrently attempt modifications on the 128bits or the high/low 64bit (that is, intermixed operations): write 128, read 64, write 64, read 128... which are not quite guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to be able to use all members of the union simultaneously:

Portably, no. This is not going to have defined behavior: consider that one or both types may be implemented with mutexes to provide locking.

Restricted to a specific implementation on which all atomic types involved have lockfree implementions, it's very likely to work correctly, or least as correctly as would be the case for a similar union of non-atomics.

Comment: Well, C++11 allows to have non-POD unions, so as long as you follow all the rules and don't forget to invoke the ctor/dtor manually... Too fiddly though.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Sorry, I forget to specify the assumption that OP wants to modify all the members simultaneously, which was my reading of "Several threads will read and write both parts of the union."

Comment: that would result in undefined behaviour